# Azure Stream Analytics job failing with "Query compilation error" but same query runs when i test it individually

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

Hi I am parsing a complex json in ASA, My input is blob and output is SQL DB, When i run Azure stream analytics query and test it it runs fine and gives the result(i am manually giving input data from file to test the query), But when i start the stream analytics job it gives me the following error

```
 "JobFailedMessage": "The streaming job failed: Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Query compilation error: Expression is not supported: 'GetArrayElement ( message . Body . NewRx . MedicationPrescribed , 0 ) . CompoundInformation . FinalCompoundPharmaceuticalDosageForm'..",
```

The complete query is

```
    SELECT 
message.Header.MessageID        src_msg_id                    
,prescriberSPI   as msg_pbr_spi                  
,eventProducedTime   as evt_produce_dttm             
,correlationId   as correlation_id               
,transactionType     as msg_txn_type                 
,message.Header.RelatesToMessageID   as relate_to_msg_id             
,message.Header.SentTime     as msg_sent_dttm                
,message.Header.SenderSoftware.SenderSoftwareDeveloper   as sndr_software_developer_name 
,message.Header.SenderSoftware.SenderSoftwareProduct     as sndr_software_prod__name     
,message.Header.SenderSoftware.SenderSoftwareVersionRelease  as sndr_software_vers_release   
,message.Header.RxReferenceNumber.encValue   as rx_ref_nbr                   
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderNumber    as pbr_ord_nbr                  
,message.Header.DigitalSignature.DigitalSignatureIndicator   as dgtl_signature_ind          
,message.Header.DigitalSignature.DigestMethod    as dgtl_signature_digest_method
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.OrderGroupNumber    as ord_group_nbr                
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.ItemCountInOrderGroup   as item_cnt_in_ord_group        
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.TotalCountForOrderGroup     as tot_cnt_for_ord_group        
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.OrderGroupReason    as ord_group_reason             
,message.Body.NewRx.UrgencyIndicatorCode     as urgency_cd                   
,message.Body.NewRx.ChangeOfPrescriptionStatusFlag   as rx_stat_chng_cd              
,message.Body.NewRx.FollowUpRequest  as followup_reqst_nbr           
,message.Body.NewRx.AllergyOrAdverseEvent.NoKnownAllergies   as allergy_no_known_ind         
,GetArrayElement(message.Body.NewRx.MedicationPrescribed,0).CompoundInformation.FinalCompoundPharmaceuticalDosageForm    as fnl_cmpnd_dosage_form_cd     
,GetArrayElement(message.Body.NewRx.Observation,0).ObservationNotes  as observation_note             
from blobinput
```

This query works perfect when i run it in query tab and select test and it produces the output, but when i start the job it errors out saying 
**The streaming job failed: Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Query compilation error: Expression is not supported: 'GetArrayElement ( message . Body . NewRx . MedicationPrescribed , 0 )**

Comment: can you post a sample row from your input?

Comment: its a PII data so can not post here, but i have written similar query for a different dataset. That also has the same problem. the query works fine when running in query tab and press test. but when i start a job the job fails. The query is SELECT
    id,
 type,
 name,
 GetArrayElement(batters.batter, 0).id AS firstid,
 GetArrayElement(topping, 0).id AS topingid
FROM ncpdpehub

Comment: the data is : { "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "ppu": 0.55, "batters":  {   "batter":    [     { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },     { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },     { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },     { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }    ]  }, "topping":  [   { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },   { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },   { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },   { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },   { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" }, { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },   { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }  ]}

Answer (score 2):

Please try splitting the query into 2 steps, so there is no immediate referencing of the GetArrayElement() result.
Something like:

```
WITH Step1 AS (
SELECT 
message.Header.MessageID        src_msg_id                    
,prescriberSPI   as msg_pbr_spi                  
,eventProducedTime   as evt_produce_dttm             
,correlationId   as correlation_id               
,transactionType     as msg_txn_type                 
,message.Header.RelatesToMessageID   as relate_to_msg_id             
,message.Header.SentTime     as msg_sent_dttm                
,message.Header.SenderSoftware.SenderSoftwareDeveloper   as sndr_software_developer_name 
,message.Header.SenderSoftware.SenderSoftwareProduct     as sndr_software_prod__name     
,message.Header.SenderSoftware.SenderSoftwareVersionRelease  as sndr_software_vers_release   
,message.Header.RxReferenceNumber.encValue   as rx_ref_nbr                   
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderNumber    as pbr_ord_nbr                  
,message.Header.DigitalSignature.DigitalSignatureIndicator   as dgtl_signature_ind          
,message.Header.DigitalSignature.DigestMethod    as dgtl_signature_digest_method
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.OrderGroupNumber    as ord_group_nbr                
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.ItemCountInOrderGroup   as item_cnt_in_ord_group        
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.TotalCountForOrderGroup     as tot_cnt_for_ord_group        
,message.Header.PrescriberOrderGroup.OrderGroupReason    as ord_group_reason             
,message.Body.NewRx.UrgencyIndicatorCode     as urgency_cd                   
,message.Body.NewRx.ChangeOfPrescriptionStatusFlag   as rx_stat_chng_cd              
,message.Body.NewRx.FollowUpRequest  as followup_reqst_nbr           
,message.Body.NewRx.AllergyOrAdverseEvent.NoKnownAllergies   as allergy_no_known_ind         
,GetArrayElement(message.Body.NewRx.MedicationPrescribed,0) as MedicationPrescribed
,GetArrayElement(message.Body.NewRx.Observation,0) as Observation
from blobinput
)

Select
 src_msg_id                    
,msg_pbr_spi                  
,evt_produce_dttm             
,correlation_id               
,msg_txn_type                 
,relate_to_msg_id             
,msg_sent_dttm                
,sndr_software_developer_name 
,sndr_software_prod__name     
,sndr_software_vers_release   
,rx_ref_nbr                   
,pbr_ord_nbr                  
,dgtl_signature_ind          
,dgtl_signature_digest_method
,ord_group_nbr                
,item_cnt_in_ord_group        
,tot_cnt_for_ord_group        
,ord_group_reason             
,urgency_cd                   
,rx_stat_chng_cd              
,followup_reqst_nbr           
,allergy_no_known_ind         
,MedicationPrescribed.CompoundInformation.FinalCompoundPharmaceuticalDosageForm    as fnl_cmpnd_dosage_form_cd     
,Observation.ObservationNotes  as observation_note      
INTO output       
from Step1
```

Comment: Thanks Sasha, This solution works, But this way the performance will be degraded. I was wondering why the same query works in Query tab but not with the job. This seems to be a bug in ASA. Anyways Thanks a lot for the workaround.

Comment: I am trying to do this but the query editor is throwing "incorrect syntax near INTO"

Comment: Thanks @MartinHatch, the INTO must come after the select properties... my bad, updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved in the compatibility level 1.2 , From the Azure Streaming Analytics portal select the compatibility level 1.2(default is 1.1).